# Derivative in R and finding value at a point

Tags: r, function, derivative

I have `t^3 / sqrt(1 - t^2)`
Which I want to find the third derivative to and then finding the value at *t*=0. I want to do this in R. I have tried

```
dddft <- function(t) {D(D(D(expression((t^3) / (sqrt(1-t^2))), "t"), "t"), "t")}
```

And then I try

```
dddft(0)
```

But doing this just gives me a long expression and not at *t*=0.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate expression with `eval()` that it can be run.

```
dddft <- function(t) eval(D(D(D(expression((t^3) / (sqrt(1-t^2))), "t"), "t"), "t"))

dddft(0)
# [1] 6
```

To avoid painful nesting, you could use this function (see `?D`):

```
DD <- function(expr, name, order = 1) {
  if(order < 1) stop("'order' must be >= 1")
  if(order == 1) D(expr, name)
  else DD(D(expr, name), name, order - 1)
}

dddft <- function(x) eval(DD(expression(x^3 / sqrt(1 - x^2)), "x", 3))
dddft(0)
# [1] 6
```